# How to create Unique User Dashboards in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, dashboard, user-management

thank you for opening this thread. I am designing a wordpress website and I want users to have the ability to login, register and also have a unique user dashboard where I can control what each user sees on their dashboards.

I have created a successful user registration and login system, but the problem I have is that all the users get to view the same page after they login, there is just one general account page all the users see. But I want it to be more unique. I want all the users to see their personal user dashboard so I can send different message to different users.

I am trying to do all of this with WORDPRESS using Elementor site builder, I do not know how to code or write PHP. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/frontend-admin/. If you want to do this with code you will need to do lots of things like functions, templates, users capabilities etc with good knowledge of code. For easy you can use this plugin. Its basically working as user frontend admin same work as WP admin dashboard but you will provide the capabilities and privileges according to your requirements, and its working with Elementor builder.
Thanks.